# How to display & add validation to radio button group based on other radio button group value

Tags: angular

In my Angular app, I have 2 radio groups.

`Injury Type` *radio group* is always required.

`Damage Reported to Police` *radio group* should only be displayed & required when the *Burglary in the car* option of the `Injury Type` radio group is selected.

Here is what I currently have at the moment:

Typescript:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.myForm = this.fb.group({
        damageDetailsTwoForm: this.fb.group({
            injuryTypeGp: this.fb.group({
                injuryType: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
                damageReportedToPolice: new FormControl('')
                }),
            })
        });
}
```

[image: screenshot]

Both radio groups are displaying.

Here is what I currently have:

```
<div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label">Injury Type:</label>
                    <radio-button-wrapper (getSelectedItem)="getSelectedItem($event)" formControlName="injuryType"
                      name="injuryType" updateOn="click">
                      <radio cid="Bumps, scratches & damage" class="_text-bold" name="insuredType"
                        value="Bumps, scratches & damage" heading="Bumps, scratches & damage" data-orientation="inline">
                      </radio>
                      <radio cid="Replacement of windows etc." name="insuredType"
                        value="Replacement of windows etc." heading="Replacement of windows etc."
                        data-orientation="inline">
                      </radio>
                      <radio cid="Burglary in the car" name="insuredType" value="Burglary in the car"
                        heading="Burglary in the car" data-orientation="inline">
                      </radio>
                      <radio cid="Destroyed roof box, bicycle etc." name="insuredType"
                        value="Destroyed roof box, bicycle etc." heading="Destroyed roof box, bicycle etc."
                        data-orientation="inline">
                      </radio>
                      <radio cid="Wrong fuel" name="insuredType" value="Wrong fuel" heading="Wrong fuel"
                        data-orientation="inline">
                      </radio>
                      <radio cid="Theft of license plates" name="insuredType" value="Theft of license plates"
                        heading="Theft of license plates" data-orientation="inline">
                      </radio>
                    </radio-button-wrapper>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">                    
                    <label class="control-label">Damage Reported to Police:</label>
                    <radio-button-wrapper formControlName="damageReportedToPolice" name="damageReportedToPolice"
                      updateOn="click">
                      <radio cid="Yes" class="_text-bold" name="damageReportedToPolice" value="Yes" heading="Yes"
                        data-orientation="inline">
                      </radio>
                      <radio cid="No" class="_text-bold" name="damageReportedToPolice" value="No" heading="No"
                        data-orientation="inline">
                      </radio>
                    </radio-button-wrapper>
                  </div>
```

Can someone please tell me what I need to do in order to meet the above requirement? Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add conditional validator function to second group after form has been initialized.

```js
ngOnInit() {
    this.myForm = this.fb.group({
        damageDetailsTwoForm: this.fb.group({
            injuryTypeGp: this.fb.group({
                injuryType: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
                damageReportedToPolice: new FormControl('')
            }),
        })
    });

    this.myForm.controls.damageReportedToPolice.setValidators(() => {
        return this.myForm.controls.injuryType.value === 'Burglary in the car'
            ? [Validators.required]
            : [];
    });
}
```

And wrap your second group in HTML with `*ngIf="myForm.controls.injuryType?.value === 'Burglary in the car'"`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I may have worded it incorrectly, but the requirement is a bit tricky. The second group should only be displayed if _Burglary in the car_ is selected in the first group. That second group should not appear for any other answer from the first group. Does this make sense? Or is there a better way to structure it?

Comment: My bad. Updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Keep the groupB radio button set hidden until the user chooses the required value in groupA. On change of radio buttons of groupA, set a boolean flag to show/hide groupB based on the GroupA cvalue

Component:

`showGroupB: boolean`

```
getSelectedItem(data) {
    console.log(data);
    if (data.value === 'Replacement of windows etc.') {
        // based on required condition
        showGroupB = true
    } else {
        showGroupB = false
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group" *ngIf="showGroupB">
        <label class="control-label">Damage Reported to Police:</label>
        <radio-button-wrapper formControlName="damageReportedToPolice" name="damageReportedToPolice" updateOn="click">
            <radio cid="Yes" class="_text-bold" name="damageReportedToPolice" value="Yes" heading="Yes" data-orientation="inline">
            </radio>
            <radio cid="No" class="_text-bold" name="damageReportedToPolice" value="No" heading="No" data-orientation="inline">
            </radio>
        </radio-button-wrapper>
    </div>
```